# Connector/net does not support server versions prior to 5.0 after downgrading connector/net and mysql server version

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Hi I believe there have been some similar topics regarding connector/ net not supporting server versions prior to 5.0.

I have been trying add in a connection to a database in visual studio 2013 and I am not able to connect due to the server version being 4.1.2 I am unable to upgrade this databases server as its out of my hands.

What I have done is follow the suggested answers which is downgrade the connector/ net prior to 5.0 and downgrade the mysql server to 4.1.

I have added in the reference and its still giving me the same error.

Can anyone suggest anything else I could try or may be missing?

Cheers guys I'm pretty desperate now!!

Answer (score 0):

See [MySQL Connector/Net Developer Guide - Connector/Net Versions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html). This document contains table that shows the .NET Framework version required, and the MySQL Server version supported by Connector/Net.

For MySQL Server 4.1 you may need to install Connector/NET v. 6.2 and .NET Framework 2.x

Answer (score 0):

what you must do is, install a lower NuGet that supports the version you have of maria db, in my case, I install the MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.11 and it will work without problem.